# What's the best way to create groups/collections of objects (of the same model) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application which asks users questions, then (depending on the answer) passes through the relevant next_question to the controller - a kind of state machine/decision tree. For one use-case I need the ability to group together a set of answers, then loop back to the beginning question of the group and start building another group following the same chain.

So far I can direct the controller to start a new chain, but the existing chain just sort of floats there, and I want to segregate it into groups. As such I've defined certain questions as "collectable" by adding a column to the DB `add_column :collectable, :boolean, default: false` and flagging those I want to group together by setting that column to true. This works fine.

In the model, these items are called `SaleQualifiers` each `has_one :answer` and `belongs_to :question` (the question model holds the collectable information). On my SaleQualifiers model I have added a column `collection_id, :integer` - so the plan is to use some logic that will check whether a SaleQualifier's question is collectable or not, then pass an id to the collection_id column which I'll use to group these objects in the display and in the routing logic (for e.g. editing a SaleQualifier).

How do you go about setting the id's of a column outside of the standard Rails controlled id allocation? What would be the safest way of doing this? For my purposes I probably want to give more than one SaleQualifier the id=1, because SaleQualifiers belong_to SalesOpportunities and I can scope the SaleQualifier by the parent SalesOpportunity_id.

Any recommendations?

Comment: 'Setting the id's of a column' - do you mean you want to set the value of collection_id or do you want to set the id of an instance of SalesQualifier?

Comment: Set the value of the collection_id - I don't want to change the id of the SaleQualifier itself